# Grep -A1 format output

Tags: grep

I have 10 files with several IP ping test results

```
--- 10.90.101.224 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
Some Text here...
--- 10.90.101.225 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
Some Text here...
--- 10.90.101.226 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

i used > `grep -A1 'ping statistics' *.log` and got the output below

```
--- 10.90.101.224 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--- 10.90.101.225 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--- 10.90.101.226 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

i wanted to get the output with the format below

```
--- 10.90.101.224 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--- 10.90.101.225 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--- 10.90.101.226 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

Comment: Why are there no group separators `--` in your output when you use `-A1`?

Comment: Sorry, there is a -- separator.

Comment: --- 10.90.101.224 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--
--- 10.90.101.225 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
--
--- 10.90.101.226 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste`:

```
grep -A1 'ping statistics' *.log | paste - -
```

`paste` will per default add a tab between the lines, change this to a space with `paste -d ' ' - -`.

Comment: Thank you so much this work!
grep --no-group-separator -A1 'ping statistics' *.log | paste -d " " - -

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs`

```
grep -A1 'ping statistics' *.log | xargs -n 15
```

`-n max-args`
 Use at most max-args arguments per command line.